# How to determine if an app is using UIWebView instead of native UI components

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

There are many apps implement UI with UIWebView and HTML.

The HTML5 is very powerful, that I could hardly tells the difference between cocoa components and HTML elements.

Is there any method to determine whether the app is using HTML instead of cocoa components?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently implementing a application that the UI view is just a UIWebView pointing to a web site.

It depends on how much like a ios "app" the web site looks like.  The only difference I can see is the loading speed of graphics from a web site is slower than locally stored graphics in a app. If you crafted the web site well enough, you would not be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference in look and feel of WebView app and native applications.. Main difference is UI responsiveness. Native applications tend to behave snappier, table views in those applications scroll more naturally, buttons and controls are more responsive.

It can't be explained in few lines, but you should feel it when using application. We made few cross platform apps with web technologies, and they can't be compared to native ones... No matter how hard we tried to emulate native behaviors...

Comment: I was shocked by the m.google.com on iphone.  I feel it is even greater than the native app.